# ggplot2: How to nudge the position of points in geom_beeswarm?

Tags: r, ggplot2, position

I'm preparing a boxplot which should display both the boxplot as well as datapoints. The datapoints should be nudged on the right while the boxplot should be on the left.

I use the geom_beeswarm function of the R-Package ggbeeswarm to avoid overlapping points, similar to geom_jitter.

However, because I want to add a boxplot on the left, I want to move the data points horizontally to the right so that there is space on the left for a boxplot.

I have tried around with position = position_nudge(x = 0.5) but the parameter is unknown for geom_beeswarm. The same goes for nudge_x=0.5.

Does someone have another solution to move the geom_beeswarm plots to the right?

## Reproducible example

```
df <- data.frame('variable'=rep(c('control','treatment'),each=20),
'value'=c(runif(20, min=0, max=3), rnorm(60)))

ggtest<-ggplot(df,aes(variable, value)) +
geom_beeswarm(priority='random',cex=2.5)
ggtest
```

Comment: It might be too funky for your purposes, but I've seen a few examples of folks doing a split boxplot and density/histogram/beeswarm. Here's one that's dubbed a raincloud plot: https://micahallen.org/2018/03/15/introducing-raincloud-plots/

Comment: These look very nice but I only have 10 data points per variable, so this is a bit "over the top".

Answer (score 4):

Try this. Basically first create a new variable which is a copy of your `"variable"`, simply use `paste0` to add a number to avoid confusion, I named it `"variable2"`.

Print the new `df` to see the difference. This new `variable2` will be used as an `aes()` for the `geom_beeswarm()`, then just use `scale_x_discrete` and play around with `theme()` to center the text on the `x-axis`.

Again I suggest to print the plot before calling `scale_x_discrete()` ecc.. to se what I mean.

```
df$variable2 <- paste0(df$variable, "2") # create a second almost identical variable

ggplot(df,aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_beeswarm(aes(variable2),priority='random',cex=2.5) + # use variable2 as custom aes() for the bees
  geom_boxplot() +
 # play with this to customize labels, we just want to hide "control2" and "treatment2"
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("control", "treatment")) + 
 # with this we center the text and remove the tick marks to improve the plot
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=-1),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank()) # removes vertical grid white lines
```

[image]

Data example:

```
library(ggbeeswarm)

df <- data.frame('variable'=rep(c('control','treatment'),each=20),
                 'value'=c(runif(20, min=0, max=3), rnorm(60)))
```

---

**Update** to answer OP request of more spacing.

I couldn't find a better way to add spacing between the `geoms`. I used the trick of creating two dummy new variables, that will be used to plot a third `geom` right beside the `beeswarm`.

This will force `ggplot` to make some spacing, and the new `geom` will be hidden by setting the same `color` as the `bg` of the `panel`.

I used `geom_boxplot()`.

New example data:

```
df <- data.frame('variable'=rep(letters[1:7],each=20),
                 'value'=c(runif(40, min=0, max=3), rnorm(100)))
df$variable2 <- paste0(df$variable, "2") # create a second almost identical variable
```

Create two new variables that we can use to plot a third object, which will be masked using the same `color` as the `bg`.

```
df$variable3 <- paste0(df$variable, "3")
df$value3 <- c(runif(40, min=0, max=3), rnorm(100))
```

Finally:

```
ggplot(df,aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_beeswarm(aes(variable2),priority='random',cex=2.5) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(variable3, value3), color="white") + # this is the boxplot that we will hide (notice the color choice)
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(letters[1:7])) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=-6), # adjust to center the x-labels
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(color="white", fill="white"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), # to remove grid lines
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = "solid",
                                 colour = "black"))
```

[image]

Again this could be adjusted even more.

Comment: Great solution, this works very well! Thank you very much!

Comment: Remember to close this by accepting and voting the answer if it's what you needed.

Comment: I now tried to implement this in my plot with 7 variables. The problem is that it would be better to have the control boxplot close to the control points and the treatment boxplot close to the treatment points. while the gap between the two variable should be larger.
Any solution for this?

Comment: @Dominic_Mart updated with a solution, you should be able to play with this to make the plot look prettier. Unfortunately I couldn't find a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and the existing solution with dummy categories did not satisfy me, so I wrote a `position_nudge_any` which takes whatever positioning function, then applies extra "nudge" when it finishes.

```r
#' Nudge any other positioning function from ggplot2
#' @param x Nudge in X direction
#' @param y Nudge in Y direction
#' @param position Any positioning operator from ggplot2 like \link{position_jitter}[ggplot2]
#' @return A combination positioning operator which first runs the original positioning,
#' then adds a nudge on top of that
#' @export
position_nudge_any <- function(x = 0, y = 0, position) {
  ggproto(NULL, PositionNudgeAny,
          nudge = ggplot2::position_nudge(x, y),
          position = position
  )
}


#' Internal class doing the actual nudging on top of the other operation
#' @keywords internal
PositionNudgeAny <- ggplot2::ggproto("PositionNudgeAny", ggplot2::Position,
  nudge = NULL,
  nudge_params = NULL,
  position = NULL,
  position_params = NULL,

  setup_params = function(self, data) {
   list(nudge = self$nudge,
        nudge_params = self$nudge$setup_params(data),
        position = self$position,
        position_params = self$position$setup_params(data))
  },

  setup_data = function(self, data, params) {
   data <- params$position$setup_data(data, params$position_params)
   params$nudge$setup_data(data, params$nudge_params)
  },

  compute_layer = function(self, data, params, layout) {
   data <- params$position$compute_layer(data, params$position_params, layout)
   params$nudge$compute_layer(data, params$nudge_params, layout)
  }
)
```

Then you can change your example to this:

```r
df <- data.frame('variable'=rep(c('control','treatment'),each=20),
'value'=c(runif(20, min=0, max=3), rnorm(60)))

ggtest<-ggplot(df,aes(variable, value)) +
geom_point(position=position_nudge_any(x=0.25, y=0, ggbeeswarm::position_beeswarm(priority='random',cex=2.5))
ggtest
```

[image: beeswarm with dots nudged to the left]